# Brew services start but postgresql94 does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew, ruby-on-rails-4.1

### Current situation:

I'm trying to install and run `postgresql 9.4` via `homebrew`.

It installs fine, and when I run `brew services start postgresql94`, it says it started correctly.

However there is no `postgres` process running in `ps` and `psql` can't connect.

I can start it with `postgres -D`, but trying to log in via `psql -U postgres` tells me that the `postgres` role doesn't exist and I can't figure out another default to using. (my local user also doesn't exist as a role)

### How I got here:

I'm trying to set up a new dev environment with an existing `Rails 4.1.8` app.

I originally installed `postgresql 9.5` via `homebrew` which worked happily until I attempted to migrate which failed with [this error](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23039).

I cannot upgrade to a newer version of `Rails`.  I've searched around a bunch and I'm surprised more people haven't run into this problem.

If you have any suggestions to either of the above I would really appreciate it.

Comment: try creating a new user `createuser --pwprompt toppy42` and then login into psql console using this command: `psql -U toppy42 -W myapp_development`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new admin user with password 'secret':

```
psql -c "create role admin password 'secret' superuser createdb createrole inherit login";
```

or, try prepending `sudo -u postgres bash -c`

```
"sudo -u postgres bash -c psql -c \"create role ..\""
```

If this still gives you an error message such as 'FATAL: role "admin" does not exist", you might want to do a fresh install. On a fresh install you have a default superuser named 'postgres' with no password and you should be able to login with

```
psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first command to create the postgres user and now everything is happy (including `brew services`).  What's weird is that this is a fresh install.  I removed all references to postgres before brew installing.  Marking as answer